# How to pass arguments into variables to eventually execute in a batch file?

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, command-prompt

I'm looking to create an App file wrapper that will take 3 arguments with an optional 4th argument.  The 1st argument will be the location of a directory that needs "work" done, the 2nd and 3rd arguments should be appended together as one argument to run an application, and the 4th argument will be a switch.

Ex: `AppFileWrapper C:\Application\ App begin-work -New`

1st argument: C:\Application

2nd argument: App

3rd argument: begin-work

4th argument (optional): -New

What I need is a batch file that will automatically navigate to the given directory, and then execute the remaining arguments as: "App begin-work -New"

I've created the following batch file

```
cd %1
set var1=%2 %3 %4
```

Now how to just call var1 or "App begin-work -New" or "App begin-work" as specified by the parameters.

Thanks, I'm completely new to creating batch files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd %1
start %2 %3 %4
```

should work.

Comment: Make that `cd /d %1`. This way, it will change the current directory even if it's on a different drive.

Comment: Is there a way to run all this in the same command prompt window?  I noticed that the "start" command opens a completely new command prompt window.  The reason being is that I plan on redirecting the console output to a GUI window, and it doesn't look like that works when a new window is opened up when using the Process class.

Comment: Why bother with a bat file then?  Just kick off a new Process with the desired parameters.